# insert image into oracle database with asp.net web forms visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, visual-studio-2012

how to store image file in oracle database connected with asp.net web forms application (visual studio 2012).
please be informed that i'm using EF.

```
myContext db=new myContext();
public class MyClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string imgName { get; set; }
    public BLOB img { get; set; }
}

public void storeImage_Click(string imgPath)
{
    MyClass h = new MyClass();
    h.imgName="somename";
    h.img=imgPath;
    db.MyClass.Add(h);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: i don't know how to convert img file to byte [], frankly i want to know the way that works.     thank you in advanced Sir.  @OldProgrammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OracleClient;

public void storeImage_Click(string imgPath)
{
    FileStream fls;
    fls = new FileStream(imgPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    //a byte array to read the image 
    byte[] blob = new byte[fls.Length];
    fls.Read(blob, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fls.Length));
    fls.Close();

    db.MyClass.Add(blob);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

You will need to add your image using a Parameter

```
OracleParameter blobParameter = new OracleParameter();
blobParameter.OracleType = OracleType.Blob;
blobParameter.ParameterName = "MyImage";
blobParameter.Value = blob;
```

To get the image back from the database and save to disk

dataRow[0] = your image from the database

```
FileStream FS = new FileStream("image.jpg", FileMode.Create); 
byte[] blob = (byte[])dataRow[0]; 
FS.Write(blob,0,blob.Length); 
FS.Close(); 
FS = null; 

pctimg.Image = Image.FromFile("image.jpg");
```